# Unknown Provider error using Karma with Angular

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have a module

```
export default angular.module('pfui.user', [])
    .controller('ModifyUserController', ModifyUserController)
```

that has a controller

```
export default class ModifyUserController{ 
    userid:string;
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to create a unit test that can test some methods in the controller that calls services to do some operation. This is my Karma script -

```
describe('ModifyUserControllerTester', function () {
    var $controller;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('pfui.user'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('Test', function () {
        it('test accessing controller', function () {
            let $scope = {};
                var controller = $controller('ModifyUserController', {
                $scope: $scope
             });
            expect($scope['userid']).toBe(undefined);
        });
    });
});
```

When I run the test, I get an error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UsersProvider <- Users <- ModifyUserController
```

Initially I was getting an error that $stateProvider was missing. So I added

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));
```

and that error went away.

This is my first attempt in writing a Karma test. I'm not sure what I am missing. Why is Karma looking for a Provider when I don't have one in the module? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your controller's constructor look like? If it has `Users` as an argument, where is that defined? Also can't see any reason why you'd get an error about `ui.router`, it doesn't appear as one of your module's dependencies.

Comment: @Phil, your comment sent me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't show any dependency injections to the ModifyUserController but going by the error you have posted it looks like you haven't provided the 'Users' Service to the controller.

```
describe('ModifyUserControllerTester', function () {
    var $controller;
    var mockUsers;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('pfui.user'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('Test', function () {
        it('test accessing controller', function () {
        //----define your mock dependency here---//
        let mockUsers = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockUsers', ['user_method1', 
            'user_method2',...]);
            let $scope = {};
                var controller = $controller('ModifyUserController', {
                $scope: $scope,
                Users: mockUsers
            });
            expect($scope['userid']).toBe(undefined);
        });
    });
});
```

PS. Since its best practice for unit tests to be conducted in isolation, you should also consider providing a mock state provider vs importing the actual ui.router module

Comment: You are right. I missed the dependencies. ui-router was also a dependency which is why it was complaining. It works now. Thanks!!